# Go to specific Activity on notification group click

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I am not asking how to start an activity from an "individual" notification. I am interested in how to navigate to a specific activity on a group notification click. Is there a way that I can bind an intent to a specific notification group? Android provides a `setGroup()` method to specify the notification group, how can I including an intent for notification groups in the event that a user clicks on the notification group, and not a specific notification within the group.

A good example is WhatsApp, when you click on the message group notification, you will go to an activity where you see all the conversations for messages you have. However, if the user clicks on a specific notification in the message group, they will be directed to the specific conversation for that message, where they can immediately send a message. I want to do something similar to this.